# Possible for batch size of neural network to be too small?

Tags: neural-networks

We know that when a batch size is too large, the model might not be able to converge. But what is the drawback of having a batch size be too small (say `batch_size` = 1) other than taking a long time to train? A batch size of 32 is commonly used and referred to as "small," but why don't we use a smaller batch size of 1 to guarantee convergence?

Comment: batch size 1 is sometimes used -- usually when no larger batch will fit in GPU memory

Comment: Or when data arrives in a stream, like in online learning.